# Why 'p.class or li#id' doesn't get applied when I use in this format?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have seen in many css tutorials, syntax like p.class or p#id
Eg.

```
p.center
```

But I always have to use `class p{ }`, otherwise it doesn't get applied.

Any suggestions?

```css
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li#nav {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="first.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="icon">
    <h1>icon</h1>

    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: maybe you are not using it right. In HTML, you need to use `<p class="my-class">...</p>` or `<p id="my-id">...</p>`. Can you give us your code examples?

Comment: Please provide both exampes (html+css) what does work for you and what doesn't explain why you expect the second one should work and we'll certainly explain why it doesn't. If an answer given already have made the issue clear, don't forget to accept it. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
li.list {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="first.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="icon">
    <h1>icon</h1>

    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="list"><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li class="list"><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li class="list"><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So, element.classname means, element must be having a class with `classname`. Same goes for id. But, remember `#id` is always unique. So, prefer classname in such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

p.center{} refers to  p elements with 'center' class and .center p {}  refers to 
 all p elements inside element having .center class. So based on your html structure you can have css selectors .

You can refer from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Also, you are trying to make a change to the `P` element in your html.

In css you just need to do `p{}` but that would change all the `P` on your page which is normally not a good idea unless you are 110% sure that is what you want, no matter what.